# How to check iOS device is in silent mode or in ring mode when user calls through internet in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, linphone, callkit

I am making an app SIP calling by using Linphone .here I am having some problem when my phone is on silent mode it shows me vibration on the other hand when it is on general mode than it rings. I am not getting any code. what will be the condition for this problem? please help me out.

Thanks.